# Meteor+React element duplication

Tags: html, meteor, reactjs

I'm trying to create the structure of a basic Meteor app with React:
This is the main.html

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="render-target"></div>
</body>
```

this is the startup function

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
    ReactDOM.render(<AppLayout />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
});
```

and this is the app layout

```
AppLayout = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="wrapper">
                {this.props.nav}
                {this.props.content}
                {this.props.footer}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

from what I understand the

```
ReactDOM.render(<AppLayout />, document.getElementById("render-target"));
```

should replace the div "render-target" with the AppLayout element (the "wrapper" div), but when i run the app, inside the body i see two div: the "render-target" and the "react-root". 
[As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sug2R.png)

why is the "render-target" div still there and the "wrapper" is duplicated?

EDIT: 
the router part is

```
FlowRouter.route("/", {
    name: "HomePageRoute",

    action:function() {
        ReactLayout.render(AppLayout, {
            nav: <NavBar />,
            content: <HomePageContainer />,
            footer: <Footer/>
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ReactDOM.render(<AppLayout />, document.getElementById("render-target"));`

Will not replace the `render-target` id, that will always exist. As for the duplicate, I've never seen that "accidentally" happen. If you could show your whole code I'm almost certain we'll find that you have something else rendering to that element.

What packages are you using? What version of meteor? What router? Those are all important to know here.

In the end, I'd recommend using `react-template-helpers` for this as it's a lot more clear what's going on when using meteor + react. An example of it's usage is available from this [meteor starter boilerplate](https://github.com/thatgibbyguy/tgg-meteor-boilerplate).

Comment: I'm using meteor 1.2.1, FlowRouter with ReactLayout, (i've edited the question adding the router part)

Comment: Ok i think that the problem is with the Router.

Comment: Yes so `ReactLayout` is inserting your component + you are manually inserting it, therefore the duplicate. This is why I recommend `react-template-helpers` as they will allow you to see directly where you are inserting it, reducing the confusion of why your component is rendering twice.

Comment: So basically the problem is that ReactLayout inside the Router is executed before the Meteor.startup, and thus the AppLayout is not yet created and the ReactLayout create a component giving the "react-root" id?

Comment: No, `ReactLayout` says "render react to this layout" (which is #root) and so it does so. Then you also have code that renders it to a specific id as well, so you have react rendering twice.